# PageBuilder: Problem with the site header

Tags: wordpress, themes, settings

Despite my research on StackOverFlow and even on the PageBuilder by SiteOrigin publisher's forum. Either I did not find my answer, or it is no longer valid with the current version, 2.11.8.

I would like to know if there is a "canva page" or blank page mode, or a way to remove the title from the page, basically I would like the page to start at the black banner. And on wordpress, in the PageBuilder settings, I haven't found anything that it can do the job, and even with the custom css it doesn't totally work.

[the screenshot of the site][1]

I would like to know if there is a "canva page" or blank page mode, or a way to remove the title from the page, basically I would like the page to start at the black banner. And on wordpress, in the PageBuilder settings, I haven't found anything that it can do the job, and even with the custom css it doesn't totally work.
I followed this forum: https://siteorigin.com/thread/remove-theme-header-for-page-builder/ but there is still the white banner that I want removed.

And the layout comes from the PageBuilder library and not from a theme.
Thank you
[1]: https://i.imgur.com/1JbGPSM.png

Answer (score 0):

The theme controls the output of the page title. At this stage, Page Builder doesn't add a blank canvas template to themes. If you're using SiteOrigin Corp or many of our other themes you can use the Page Settings section on each page to remove the page title, sidebar, footer widgets, and other attributes. Other themes might also offer page-level settings or use Page Templates to do the same.